# User Defined Function Returning Empty Dataframe before Running For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, for-loop

I know questions very similar to mine have been asked many times, but I have just about reviewed them all and cannot solve my own code, so I'm hoping someone has the answer.

I'm trying to loop through csv downloads and append them together inside a user-defined function that calls a for loop. I've added in print lines so that I can see where the function fails. The function prints 1, 2, 3 and the returns dataframe df that is empty.

Why is the for loop getting skipped and the df returning empty? When run outside of the user-designed function, it works perfectly.

Thanks in advance!

```
    # LoadPackages
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pandas as pd

# ==================================================    download spp tie flows
# set directories
directory = r"E:/Data/sophie/line vision/sources/spp public/downloaded/"
driverPath = r"/Users/sophi/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"

# define urls
page_url = "https://marketplace.spp.org/pages/historical-tie-flow"
prefix_download_url = ("https://marketplace.spp.org/file-browser-api/download/" +
                       "historical-tie-flow?path=%2F")

xpath = "//*[@id='main-content']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/ul/li/a/span[@class='fname name' and contains(text(), '2021')]"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

def download_and_append(page_url, prefix_download_url, xpath) :
    
    driver.get(page_url)
    print(1)
    
    # create empty dataframe to append to
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    print(2)
    
    # retrieve data from page
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
    print(3)
    
    for element in elements:
        
        index = element.text.split()[0]
        print(index)
        data = pd.read_csv(prefix_download_url + index)
        print(4)
        
        # clean dataframe and concatenate to df
        df = pd.concat([df, data])
        print(5)
        
    return df

hourly_tie_flows_2021 = download_and_append(page_url, prefix_download_url, xpath)
hourly_tie_flows_2021

# ========================================================== export data

hourly_tie_flows_2021.to_csv(directory + "/spp_tie_flows_by_ba_2021.csv")`
```

Comment: Are you sure that the query  `elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)` acually finds some thing? try printing the elements before the loop to see. You may be trying to loop over a empty list.
just add `print(elements)` after 'print(3)'

Comment: Yes, the code runs perfectly outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer (add a sleep to let the javascript load completely) took 205.64 seconds to complete:

```
from time import sleep


sleep(2)
elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
```

A longer answer (Only use Selenium to get the urls. Use requests and concurrent.futures to download the files concurrently) took 35.08 seconds to complete:

```
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from io import StringIO
from time import sleep

import pandas as pd
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class Scrape:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.year = kwargs.get("year")
        self.urls = self.get_urls()
        self.output_file_path = r"E:/Data/sophie/line vision/sources/spp public/downloaded/"
        self.driver_path = r"/Users/sophi/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"

    def get_urls(self) -> list:
        root_url = "https://marketplace.spp.org"
        page_url = f"{root_url}/pages/historical-tie-flow"
        download_url = f"{root_url}/file-browser-api/download/historical-tie-flow?path="

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        driver.get(page_url)

        sleep(2)
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(text(),'{self.year}')]")

        return [f"{download_url}{x.text}" for x in elements]

    def process_urls(self) -> None:
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=os.cpu_count()) as executor:
            (pd
             .concat(executor.map(self.download_data, self.urls))
             .sort_values("GMTTIME")
             .reset_index(drop=True)
             ).to_csv(f"{self.output_file_path}/spp_tie_flows_by_ba_{self.year}.csv")

    @staticmethod
    def download_data(url: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
        with requests.Session() as request:
            response = request.get(url)
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(response.raise_for_status())

        return pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text), sep=",")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Scrape(year=2021).process_urls()
```